# Composite keys and IsRequired(false)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

How do tell EF Core if an object joined by a composite key, is not required?

My setup is like this (simplified):

```
public class ParentObject
{
    public int Key1 { get; set; }

    public int Key2 { get; set; }

    public CompositeKeyObject CompositeKeyObj { get; set; }

    // ...other properties
}

public class CompositeKeyObject
{
    public int Key1 { get; set; }

    public int Key2 { get; set; }

    public int? ChildObjectId { get; set; }

    public ChildObject ChildObj { get; set; }
}

public class ChildObject
{
    public int ChildObjectId { get; set; }

    // ... other properties
}
```

The method I have for retrieving the data  works fine, as long as `ParentObject` has a matching `CompositeObject`. But this might not always be the case, and I an trying to do that in fluent API like this:

```
modelbuilder.Entity<CompositeKeyObject).HasKey(p => new { p.Key1, p.Key2 }
modelBuilder.Entity<ParentObject>().Property(mpo => mpo.CompositeKeyObj).IsRequired(false);
```

But if I do this, I get an error:

> ParentObject.CompositeKeyObj' is of type 'CompositeKeyObject'
>   which is not supported by current database provider. Either change the
>   property CLR type or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]'
>   attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

How do I tell it, that there isn't always a matching  `CompositeKeyObject`?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ParentObject>().Property(mpo => mpo.CompositeKeyObj).IsRequired(false);
```

because FK relationships w/o explicit FK properties are [optional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#required-and-optional-relationships) by default.

But if you want to configure that explicitly, it should be through relationship fluent API (the `Property` API is for non navigation properties only):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ParentObject>()
    .HasOne(e => e.CompositeKeyObj)
    .WithMany()
    .IsRequired(false); // <--
```

Finally, if you need explicit FK properties, just make sure they are nullable - no fluent configuration is needed:

```
public class ParentObject
{
    // ...other properties    
    public int? CompositeKeyObjKey1 { get; set; }    
    public int? CompositeKeyObjKey2 { get; set; }    
    public CompositeKeyObject CompositeKeyObj { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: Actually `Key1` and `Key2` are not nullable, but there might be combinations which does not have a matching composite key. I cannot make them nullable, since they are also foreign keys to other tables. In my actual code, they refer to **process** and **status**.

Comment: If the dependent field/fields is/are non nullable and point to non existing value / combination of values in the principal, then it/they cannot create FK relationship. That's relational database requirement, and EF Core supports only physically enforce database relationships. In other words, if the question is how to EF Core to ignore the non exiting non nullable values from a relationship, the answer is - you can't.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev, Its seems `one-to-one` relationship between the `CompositeKeyObject` and `ParentObject` as there is no other primary key defined in the `ParentObject`. Isn't it?

Comment: @TanvirArjel It doesn't matter - by convention single reference navigation property creates one-to-many relationship. You can easily see that with `public class X { public int Id { get; set; } public Y Y { get; set; } }` and `public class Y { public int Id { get; set; } }`

Comment: But during dependent entity insert it would not complain about the primary duplication if occurs?

Comment: I found a workaround, by always having a `CompositeKeyObject` for each parent. Then I just let that point to a null child (`ChildObjectId = null`). This technically isn't a solution, but it is a decent workaround.